What is the role of sqlite3InitCallback in sqlite3InitOne?
In the sqlite3InitOne function（which sets sqlite3InitCallback as a callback to sqlite3_exec), there's one line that confuses me:
int sqlite3InitCallback(void *pInit, int argc, char **argv, char **NotUsed) {
    ....
    }else if( sqlite3_strnicmp(argv[2],"create ",7)==0 ){
      /* Call the parser to process a CREATE TABLE, INDEX or VIEW.
      ** But because db->init.busy is set to 1, no VDBE code is generated
      ** or executed.  All the parser does is build the internal data
      ** structures that describe the table, index, or view.
      */
      ...
      //argv[2] is a CREATE XXXX sql
      sqlite3_prepare(db, argv[2], -1, &pStmt, 0);
      ...
    }
}

The sqlite3InitCallback function receives a callback for each CREATE statement in sqlite_master and then uses sqlite3_prepare to compile it. However, the comments are confusing regarding its purpose.

What part is confusing?

because the compiled statements are not actually executed. i found a answer on sqlite forum, because SQLite has to read the sqlite_master table to initialize its internal symbol table. such as tblHash field of the Schema struct

https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/8c58951718
Found answer on sqlite forum,

SQLite has to read the sqlite_master table to initialize its internal symbol table. The symbol table is needed to determine if the name of the new table being created collides with an existing table, for example.

